# Best practice for adding a div with class around a couple of renderings

Tags: sxa, best-practices

In SXA 1.8 how do I implement having a div with classes and aria labelling around two components (eg. a link list and search box).

eg. I want:

```
  <div id="menu" class="header-content menu-collapse js-menu" aria-labelledby="open-menu" aria-hidden="true">
```

If I use a container there is no Css Class field - there is only the option to add a new Style to the site and tick that, but the intention is that it is only relevant to this one div.

I also get div class="row" being inserted which I can't see how to robustly exclude because the container.cshtml is using a dynamic placeholder id as part of the key. My elements are supposed to sit next to one another so the new row breaks the layout I'm going for.

[image]

Lastly is it correct to assume that I shouldn't make use of the id field of a container?  I did this and suddenly lost content of the container on saving, and I have a recollection of reading this fact somewhere.